# Algorithm to select random pairs, schedule matchups

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm working in Ruby, but I think this question is best asked agnostic of language. It may be assumed that we have access to basic list/array functions, as well as a "random" number generator. Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

Given a collection of `n` teams, with `n` even,

1. Randomly pair each team with an opponent, such that every team is part of exactly one pair. Call this `ROUND 1`.
2. Randomly generate `n-2` subsequent rounds (`ROUND 2` through `ROUND n-1`) such that:

   - Each round has the same property as the first (every team is a
     member of one pair), and
   - After all the rounds, every team has faced every other team exactly once.

I imagine that algorithms for doing exactly this must be well known, but as a self-taught coder I'm having trouble figuring out how to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive You are describing a [round robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament). The wikipedia page gives an algorithm.

If You need a way to randomize the schedule, randomize team order, round order, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure if this is the most efficient algorithm but:

1. Randomly assign N teams into two lists of same length n/2 (List1, List2)
2. Starting with i = 0:
3. Create pairs: List1[i],List2[i] = a team pair
4. Repeat for i = 1-> (n/2-1)

   For rounds 2-> n/2-1:
5. Rotate List2, so that the first team in List2 is now at the end.
6. Repeat steps 2 through 5, until List2 has been cycled once.

Comment: This might work, but it seems that the process is deterministic once the first round is set. I want randomness (within the constraints) at every stage. (Obviously the final round will be deterministic.)

Comment: Also, how will the teams within each list ever play one another? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

This link was very helpful to me the last time I wrote a round robin scheduling algorithm.  It includes a C implementation of a first fit algorithm for round robin pairings.

http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/

In addition to the algorithm, he has some helpful links to other aspects of tournament scheduling (balancing home and away games, as well as rotating teams across fields/courts).

Note that you don't necessarily want a "random" order to the pairings in all cases.  If, for example, you were scheduling a round robin soccer league for 8 games that only had 6 teams, then each team is going to have to play two other teams twice.  If you want to make a more enjoyable season for everyone, you have to start worrying about seeding so that you don't have your top 2 teams clobbering the two weakest teams in their last two games.  You'd be better off arranging for the extra games to be paired against teams of similar strength/seeding.

Comment: This [newsgroup thread](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/sci.math.num-analysis.round-robin) is great!

Answer (score 0):

Based on info I found through Maniek's [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament), I went with the following:

1. A simple round robin algorithm that

   a. Starts with pairings achieved by zipping `[0,...,(n-1)/2]` and `[(n-1)/2 + 1,..., n-1]`. (So, if `n==10`, we have `0` paired with `5`, `1` with `6`, etc.)

   b. Rotates all but one team n-2 times clockwise until all teams have played each other. (So in round 2 we pair 1 with 6, 5 with 7, etc.)
2. Randomly assigns one of `[0,..., n-1]` to each of the teams.